# org-babel :results header-arg, graphics vs file

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

The [org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html) describes how to evaluate a src block and capture the results, using

```
:results <collection> <type> <format> <handling>

# i prefer to use this terminology for the four classes of option
:results <collection-method> <value-type> <result-type> <insertion-method>
```

The description of the difference between `<result-type> link` and `<result-type> graphics` isn't comprehensive. It seems to describe them together, as if they are effectively identical. However, running the following works correctly (saves plot to `./t.svg`, and inserts link to `./t.svg`)

```
#+begin_src R :results file graphics :file t.svg
x <- 1:10
y <- 2*x + rnorm(10)
plot(x, y)
#+end_src
```

But the following saves the plot as `Rplots.pdf` and inserts a link to `./t.svg`.

```
#+begin_src R :results file link :file t.svg
x <- 1:10
y <- 2*x + rnorm(10)
plot(x, y)
#+end_src
```

- Is there supposed to be any difference between the two?
- Does the difference depend on the src language being used? (the [documentation of R src blocks](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-R.html) never mentions `<result-type> link`)

Comment: I don't think there is supposed to be any difference (but only because the [documentation groups the two together](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html)) and the fact that they are treated differently by R src blocks feels like a bug to me, but I have not investigated in any detail. You might want to ask your question on the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-mailing-list.html).